# Excel formula to calculate minimum date from the cell group according to index

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

There is a table of dates, every minimum two dates are bound to one process (column tProc):

[image: Excel screenshot]

I'm looking for a formula to enter into the column mDate to get the minimal date for every tProc. E.g. in the rows 6 and 21 there should be 28.10.2021; in the rows 11 and 12 there should be the 31.10.2020; in the rows 16 and 19 there should be 25.11.2020.

I know, how to accomplish it in SQL, but I don't get it in Excel :(

Help is very appreciate.

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/minifs-function-6ca1ddaa-079b-4e74-80cc-72eef32e6599

Comment: @FlexYourData, thanks, it is the thing I was looking for :)